# OpenJPA upgrade for jakarta persistence api

Tags: jpa, openjpa, persistence.xml, jakarta-migration

I have been trying to upgrade my project to spring 3.1.0 . It currently uses OpenJpa with java persistence schema 1.x.

If I upgrade the javax.persistence packages to jakarta.persistence packages, with http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd schema or any of the schema using “http://java.sun.com” path, it compiles but at runtime it throws the error that:
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: The type "class com.x.x.x.xEntity" has not been enhanced.

I tried looking for Jakarta schema 2.2, which I am not sure is currently supported by OpenJpa, but at some places it suggests it does.

I did found the below link :
https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/openjpa-jakarta-tips.html
But I was facing the same error mentioned above even after following the steps mentioned in the link.
Am I missing something.

Also, can you please confirm, if OpenJpa supports Jakarta persistence. If yes, would you be able to provide some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Check OpenJPA version 4.0.0 with native Jakarta namespace support